# What is wrong in my code of 2d array by taking input from user using c

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, 2d, static-analysis

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,m,n;
    int a[m][n];

    printf("enter the row of matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("enter the column of matrix:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("enter the elements\n");

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("your matrix is :\n");

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter the row of matrix:3
enter the column of matrix:3
enter the elements
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
8
your matrix is :
788788788%
```

Why my output shows only 3 input of row 2 and column 2.

Comment: Maybe the program should declare the 2D array AFTER the user has entered the choices for `m` and `n`...

Comment: you first need to declare m and n that is to scan there values and afterwards initialize the array

Answer (score 1):

```
int i,j,m,n;
int a[m][n];
```

`m` and `n` have indeterminate values here. You need to declare the array after the input has been received and validated.

Note that `scanf()` returns the number of conversions it successfully performed, code should check for it.

```
if (scanf("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1) { 
     complain ();
}
```

See [A beginner's guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).